# Why does this function return data in the frontend but not the backend?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

This is a very strange issue and I am not sure where else to go with it.. I have compared this code using VScode and it all matches up. The frontend function is:

```
 public function getItemTypeList() {
        $usersItemsList = array();
        
        list($usersMaster) = self::getMasterAccountUsers();
         
        $userItems = UserItems::find()->where(['master_account' => $usersMaster])->all();
         
        foreach ($userItems as $Items)
        {
            array_push($usersItemsList, $Items->item_type_id);
        }
        
        $userItemsName = Items::find()->select(
                ['item_id', 'display_name'])
                ->where(['item_id' => $usersItemsList])
                ->orderBy(['display_name' => SORT_ASC])
                ->asArray()->all();
         
        return ArrayHelper::map($userItemsName, 'item_id', 'display_name');
    }
```

This function returns 60.
Backend Function

```
public function getItemTypeList() {
        $usersItemsList = array();
        
        list($usersMaster) = self::getMasterAccountUsers();
         
        $userItems = UserItems::find()->where(['master_account' => $usersMaster])->all();
         
        foreach ($userItems as $Items)
        {
            array_push($usersItemsList, $Items->item_type_id);
        }
        
        $userItemsName = Items::find()->select(
                ['item_id', 'display_name'])
                ->where(['item_id' => $usersItemsList])
                ->orderBy(['display_name' => SORT_ASC])
                ->asArray()->all();
         
        return ArrayHelper::map($userItemsName, 'item_id', 'display_name');
    }
```

This returns nothing. I have no idea why. The only difference is that one is located on the Frontend and One is located on the Backend. Note: The Backend function returns data just fine for my boss. But not for me.

Comment: first of all, why are there two functions with the same logic? and you need to show the getMasterAccountUsers method for both (frontend & backend) too, since they may contain user-specific logic

Comment: I have been trying to figure that out to be honest. I did not create this page. One function is from Backend\Models and the other is from Frontend\Models. Im working on moving it over to a Common\Models File.

Comment: You're going to have to do some logging/debugging. For instance, what does `self::getMasterAccountUsers();` return? Does it return a different dataset for each user?

Comment: It returns the Matster Account that belongs to the user. ````private function getMasterAccountUsers() { 
     $usersMaster = MasterAccount::find()->where(['account_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->account_id])->all();
      
     $usersMasterLocation = array();
    
     foreach ($usersMaster as $Master)
     {
      array_push($usersMasterLocation, $Master->account_id);
     }
  
     return array ($usersMasterLocation);
    }````

Comment: So yes, it does return a different dataset for each user. Therefore you're going to have to track down what each part of the code returns for each user. The code is the same, but the data being passed back and forth is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. Turns out that my user in the Database did not have an Account ID associated with it. Therefore, it was not able to associate the data.